# Call to member function hello() on null zendframework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I'm getting error

> Call to a member function buildCTCCompensationData() on null

in PayrollspendController.php on this line of code:

```
 $compData = $this->payrollspendManager->hello($postData);
```

I have checked the module.config.php and `__construct()` method but not able to find the  error. What is the issue in the code?
    Please help me to resolve me the error 
 
    I have called the method properly 
if any code is required will help 
if want view file that will also give 
Those who know zendframework help me to resolve issue

This is module.config.php

```
        'dashboard_activity_payrollspend' => [
                        'type' => Literal::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'route' => '/dashboard/employer-details/activity-manage',
                            'constraints' => [
                                'action' =>'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                            ],
                            'defaults' => [
                                'controller' => Controller\PayrollspendController::class,
                                'action' => 'add',

                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
    'controllers' => [
            'factories' => [

              Controller\PayrollspendController::class => Controller\Factory\PayrollspendControllerFactory::class
            ],
        ],
        'service_manager' => [
            'factories' => [
                Service\PayrollspendManager::class => Service\Factory\PayrollspendManagerFactory::class
            ],
        ],
```

This is my controller PayrollspendController.php

```
<?php 
namespace Dashboard\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Application\Entity\PyPayGroup;
use Application\Entity\PyPayPeriod;
//use Payroll\Form\SalaryVariationForm;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;
use Application\Entity\CommonCompanyHeader;
use Dashboard\Form\PayrollspendForm;
class PayrollspendController  extends AbstractActionController
{
 private $entityManager;
 private $sessionContainer;
 private $pyPayPeriodClass;
 private $pyPayGroupClass;
 private $companyClass;
  public function __construct($entityManager)
 {
 $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
 $this->pyPayGroupClass = $this->entityManager->getRepository(PyPayGroup::class);
 $this->pyPayPeriodClass = $this->entityManager->getRepository(PyPayPeriod::class);
 $this->companyClass = $this->entityManager->getRepository(CommonCompanyHeader::class);
 $this->commonTranslationManager = $commonTranslationManager;
 $sessionManager = new SessionManager();
 $this->sessionContainer = new Container('ContainerNamespace', $sessionManager);
 $arrLabelId =  [];
}
 public function addAction()
  {
        if ($this->sessionContainer->empId == "") {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin_user_login');
        }
        if (!in_array('PY', $this->sessionContainer->arrRole)) {

            if (!in_array('py_admin', $this->sessionContainer->arrRole)) {

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('dashboard_ess_index');
            }
        }
        $reportForm = new PayrollspendForm();
        $payGroup = $this->pyPayGroupClass->findBy([
            'ouCode' => $this->sessionContainer->ouCode,
            'langCode' => $this->sessionContainer->langCode,
            'pgActive' => 1
        ]);
        $reportForm->buildPayGroupData($payGroup);
        $company = $this->companyClass->findBy([
            'ouCode' => $this->sessionContainer->ouCode,
            'langCode' => $this->sessionContainer->langCode
        ]);
        $reportForm->buildCompanyData($company);
        $payPeriodData = ['' => 'Select'];
        $reportForm->get('payPeriod')->setValueOptions($payPeriodData);
        $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray();
       $postData['ouCode'] = $this->sessionContainer->ouCode;
       $postData['langCode'] = $this->sessionContainer->langCode;
       $compData = $this->payrollspendManager->hello($postData);
        $groupByData = [
            '' => 'Select',
            'location' => 'Location',
            'department' => 'Department',
            'cost-center' => 'Cost center'
       ];
        $reportForm->get('groupby')->setValueOptions($groupByData);
        return new ViewModel([
            'reportData' => $compData,
            'form' => $reportForm,
            'ouCode' => $this->sessionContainer->ouCode,
            'postData' => $postData,
            'langCode' => $this->sessionContainer->langCode,
            'arrLabels' => $this->arrLabels
        ]);
        $resultData->setTerminal(true);
        return $resultData;
    }
}
```

This is PayrollspendControllerFactory.php

```
<?php
namespace Dashboard\Controller\Factory;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Dashboard\Service\PayrollspendManager;
//use Application\Service\CommonTranslationManager;
use Dashboard\Controller\PayrollspendController;
class PayrollspendControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container,$requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        $payrollspendManager = $container->get(PayrollspendManager::class);
        //$hrManager = $container->get(HrManager::class);
     //   $commonTranslationManager = $container->get(CommonTranslationManager::class);

        return new PayrollspendController($entityManager);
    }
}
```

This PayrollspendManager.php

```
<?php
namespace Dashboard\Service;
//use Application\Entity\DsAnnouncement;
//use Application\Entity\TmDomain;

// The AnnouncementManager service is responsible for adding new task.
class PayrollspendManager
{

    /**
     * Doctrine entity manager.
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    // Constructor is used to inject dependencies into the service.
    public function __construct($entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
    public function hello($postData)
    {

        $headerData = $this->getAllCTCCompensationHeader($postData);
        $compData = $this->getAllCTCCompensationData($postData);

        return [
            'header' => $headerData,
            'detail' => $compData
        ];
    }

    public function getAllCTCCompensationHeader($postData)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder->select('DISTINCT(pc.pyComPayitem) as payHeader')
                ->from(PyCompensationDetails::class, 'pc')
                ->innerJoin(PyPayItemPaygroupMap::class, 'ppipm', 'with', 'ppipm.payitemCode = pc.pyComPayitem
                       AND ppipm.ouCode = pc.ouCode 
                       AND ppipm.langCode= pc.langCode 
                       AND ppipm.pgCode= pc.pgCode')
                ->where('pc.ouCode = ?1')
                ->andWhere('pc.langCode = ?2')
                ->andWhere('pc.pgCode = ?3')
                ->andWhere('pc.isModified = ?4')
                ->setParameter('1', $postData['ouCode'])
                ->setParameter('2', $postData['langCode'])
                ->setParameter('3', $postData['payGroup'])
                ->setParameter('4', 0)
                ->orderBy('ppipm.orderofProcessing', 'ASC');
        $compData = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
        $headerData = [
            '0' => 'Employee Id',
            '1' => 'Employee Name'
        ];
        foreach ($compData as $compHeader) {
            $headerData[] = $compHeader['payHeader'];
        }
        $headerData[] = 'PF';
        $headerData[] = 'ESIC';
        $headerData[] = 'Total';

        return $headerData;
    }

    /**
     * Get compensation detail data
     * 
     * @param type $postData
     * @return type
     */
    public function getAllCTCCompensationData($postData)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder->select('pc.pyComEmpid, pc.amount, pc.pyComPayitem, pi.payitemDesc, hn.empFname, hn.empMname, hn.empLname')
                ->from(PyCompensationDetails::class, 'pc')
                ->innerJoin(HrEmpid::class, 'he', 'with', 'pc.ouCode = he.ouCode 
                    and pc.langCode = he.langCode
                    and pc.pyComEmpid = he.empId'
                )
                ->innerJoin(HrEmpName::class, 'hn', 'with', 'pc.ouCode = hn.ouCode 
                    and pc.langCode = hn.langCode
                    and pc.pyComEmpid = hn.empId'
                )
                ->innerJoin(PyPayItem::class, 'pi', 'with', 'pc.ouCode = pi.ouCode 
                    and pc.langCode = pi.langCode
                    and pc.pyComPayitem = pi.payitemCode'
                )
                //->innerJoin(SmartlistData::class,'sd','with','sd.dataCode = pi.smartlistPayitemtype'
                 //)
                ->leftJoin(PyPayItemPaygroupMap::class, 'ppipm', 'with', 'ppipm.payitemCode = pi.payitemCode '
                        . 'AND ppipm.ouCode = pi.ouCode '
                        . 'AND ppipm.langCode= pi.langCode '
                        . 'AND ppipm.pgCode= pc.pgCode')
                ->where('pc.ouCode = ?1')
                ->andWhere('pc.langCode = ?2')
                ->andWhere('pc.pgCode = ?3')
                ->andWhere('pc.isModified = ?4')
                ->andWhere('he.smartlistEmpstatus != ?5')
                ->andWhere('pi.smartlistPayitemtype IN (94,99,100)')
                ->orderBy('ppipm.orderofProcessing', 'ASC')
                ->setParameter('1', $postData['ouCode'])
                ->setParameter('2', $postData['langCode'])
                ->setParameter('3', $postData['payGroup'])
                ->setParameter('4', 0)
                ->setParameter('5', 56);
               // ->orderBy('pc.pyComEmpid');
               // echo  $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL();
               //exit;

        $compData = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
       // echo  '<pre>';
        //print_r($compData);
       // exit;

        $data = [];


        if (!empty($compData)) {
            $total = 0;
            foreach ($compData as $dataC) {



        $data[$dataC['pyComEmpid']]['Employee Id'] = $dataC['pyComEmpid'];
        $data[$dataC['pyComEmpid']]['Employee Name'] = sprintf('%s %s %s', $dataC['empFname'], $dataC['empMname'], $dataC['empLname']);
        $data[$dataC['pyComEmpid']][$dataC['pyComPayitem']] = $dataC['amount'];
        $statData = $this->getStatuoryData($postData, $dataC['pyComEmpid']);
        //echo '<pre>';
       // print_r($statData);
        //exit;



                if(isset($statData['pf']) && ($statData['pf'] == 1)){
                    $parameterData = $this->getParamaterData($postData, 'pf', $dataC['pyComEmpid']);
                    $data[$dataC['pyComEmpid']]['PF'] = $this->getPFData($postData, $parameterData);
                } else {
                    $data[$dataC['pyComEmpid']]['PF'] = 0;
                }
                if(isset($statData['esic']) && ($statData['esic'] == 1)){
                    $parameterData = $this->getParamaterData($postData, 'esic', $dataC['pyComEmpid']);
                    $data[$dataC['pyComEmpid']]['ESIC'] = $this->getESICData($postData, $dataC['pyComEmpid']);
                } else {
                    $data[$dataC['pyComEmpid']]['ESIC'] = 0;
                }


                $data[$dataC['pyComEmpid']]['Total'] = $this->getCTCCompensationSum($postData, $dataC['pyComEmpid'], $data[$dataC['pyComEmpid']]['PF'], $data[$dataC['pyComEmpid']]['ESIC']);
            }
        }
   //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($data);
    //exit;
  return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get compensation sum
     * 
     * @param array $postData
     * @param string $pyComEmpid
     * @return type
     */
    public function getCTCCompensationSum($postData, $pyComEmpid, $pf, $esic)
    {
        $amountTotal = 0;
        $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder->select('SUM(pc.amount) as amount')
                ->from(PyCompensationDetails::class, 'pc')
                ->where('pc.ouCode = ?1')
                ->andWhere('pc.langCode = ?2')
                ->andWhere('pc.pgCode = ?3')
                ->andWhere('pc.pyComEmpid = ?4')
                ->andWhere('pc.isModified = ?5')
                ->setParameter('1', $postData['ouCode'])
                ->setParameter('2', $postData['langCode'])
                ->setParameter('3', $postData['payGroup'])
                ->setParameter('4', $pyComEmpid)
                ->setParameter('5', 0);

        $compData = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
        $amount = isset($compData['amount']) ? $compData['amount'] : 0;
        $amountTotal = $amount + $pf + $esic;
        return $amountTotal;
    }
}
```

This is PayrollspendManagerFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Dashboard\Service\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Dashboard\Service\PayrollspendManager;
class PayrollspendManagerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

        // Instantiate the service and inject dependencies
        return new PayrollspendManager($entityManager);
    }

}
```

This is PayrollspendForm

```
<?php

namespace Dashboard\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
//use Application\Entity\TmTask;


/**
 * This form is used to collect post data.
 */
class PayrollspendForm extends Form
{
    public $session;
    public $entityManager;
    public $ouCode;
    public $langCode;

 public function __construct()
    {
        // Define form name
        parent::__construct('payrollspend-form');

        // Set POST method for this form
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');
        $this->setAttribute('id', 'payrollspend-form');
        //$this->edit = $edit;
       // $this->ouCode = $session->ouCode;
      //  $this->langCode = $session->langCode;
       // $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->addElements();
        $this->addInputFilter();
    }
     protected function addElements()
    {
      $this->add([
            'type'  => 'select',
            'name' => 'payPeriod',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'payPeriod',
                'class'=>'form-control'
            ]
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type'  => 'text',
            'name' => 'payCalender',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'payCalender',
                'class'=>'form-control',
                'disabled' => 'disabled'
            ]
        ]);
          $this->add([
            'type'  => 'select',
            'name' => 'companyCode',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'companyCode',
                'class'=>'form-control'
            ]
        ]);


        $this->add([
            'type'  => 'select',
            'name' => 'payGroup',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'payGroup',
                'class'=>'form-control'
            ]
        ]);
         $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'startDate',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'startDate',
                'class' => 'form-control dpd1',
                'data-date-format' => "dd-mm-yyyy"
            ]
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'endDate',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'endDate',
                'class' => 'form-control dpd1',
                'data-date-format' => "dd-mm-yyyy"
            ]
        ]);
         $this->add([           
            'type'  => 'select',
            'name' => 'groupby',
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'groupby',
                'class'=>'form-control', 
                'placeholder'=>''
            ],
        ]);

         $this->add([
            'type' => 'submit',
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => [
                'value' => 'Submit',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
            ],
        ]);
}
 private function addInputFilter()
    {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $this->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
    }
    public function buildPayGroupData($payGroup) 
    {

        $payGroupData = [];

        foreach($payGroup as $data){
            $payGroupData[$data->pgCode] = $data->pgSdesc;
        }

        $this->get('payGroup')->setEmptyOption('select')->setValueOptions($payGroupData);
    }
      public function buildCompanyData($companys) 
    {
        $companyData = ['' => 'Select'];
        foreach($companys as $data){
            $companyData[$data->companyCode] = $data->companyName;
        }

        $this->get('companyCode')->setValueOptions($companyData);
    }
    public function defaultDate()
    {
        $this->get('startDate')->setValue(date('d-m-Y'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the call in `PayrollspendController::addAction()` is the problem.

```
$compData = $this->payrollspendManager->hello($postData);
```

This is because the `$this->payrollspendManager` variable has not been defined.

You can see in the `PayrollspendControllerFactory::__invoke` you have requested the service from the dependency injection container; but do not inject it into the constructor of the `PayrollspendController`.

```
 // PayrollspendControllerFactory::__invoke()
 $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
 $payrollspendManager = $container->get(PayrollspendManager::class);

 return new PayrollspendController($entityManager);
```

You should update the factory :

```
 return new PayrollspendController($entityManager, $payrollspendManager);
```

And also the constructor of the controller to allow the new argument (while you are there you can also type hint on the expected interface)

```
use \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use \Dashboard\Service\PayrollspendManager;

class PayrollspendController  extends AbstractActionController
{
   // ...
   private $entityManager;

   private $payrollspendManager;

   public function __construct(
       EntityManager $entityManager, 
       PayrollspendManager $payrollspendManager
   ){
       $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
       $this->payrollspendManager = $payrollspendManager;
   }
   // ...
}
```